calculating benefit of bunching donations with donor-advised fund
I am considering bunching several years of charitable donations into a single year with a donor-advised fund (DAF). I'm having some trouble with the calculations because it seems that there are a few variables, and would appreciate your thoughts.
The context:

My marginal tax rate is about 34% including state and local taxes
I donate about $2,500 per year to charity
I am considering bunching $10k into a donation this year to a DAF, so 4 years of donations
I would then itemize. My SALT deduction would be $10k, so with the donation I'd have $20k in itemized deductions. Therefore I would be $5,400 above the standard deduction (individual $14,600), and reduce my taxes by $(5,400 * .34) = $1,836

At first this seemed to me like a slam dunk, but it's harder to think about when you consider the broader context:

If I pull together the $10k from my paychecks now, that is $10k that I will not be immediately putting into the stock market (VT), because that's where all my excess money goes
After I setup the DAF I will no longer make additional charitable donations out of my paycheck, thus increasing my stock purchases after the DAF is setup, and it will even out after 4 years. However this will not fully offset the previous point as they will be later in time and therefore (on average) grow less
If I setup the DAF I would not be putting the money within the DAF into stocks, because it is short term-ish. Schwab recommended 60% money market and 40% fixed income. This is also a "cost" compared with the stock purchases I would otherwise make as per my first point (though the balance would be more stable which is a benefit). Technically I could put the money in the DAF into stocks, but it seems like it's violating typical asset allocation advice for my situation, so I don't think I'd do that.

Given these complexities, now I'm not sure how to calculate if it's still worth it. Can anybody help me figure out how to think about this?

Wouldn't the DAF be invested?

In most cases, you simply treat the DAF as a charity and deduct the deposits into it,  avoiding having to track all the individual donations you direct it to make. Tremendously simplified my yearly bookkeeping!

@littleadv see my last bullet point
